# How to use '! operator' with 'in operator' in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I do programming with strikNullCheks option.

When I use `! operator` with `in operator`, I got a following error.
(This is exactly what happens when I use a payload of Redux's Action.)

Is there any way to solve the problem?

Thanks you for reading :)

```
interface Interface {
    AB?: {
        a: number;
    } | {
        b: number[];
    }
}

function test(ab: Interface['AB']) {
    const ab2 = ('a' in ab!) ? [ab!.a] : ab!.b;
    => error: Property 'a' does not exist on type '{ a: number; } | { b: number[]; }'. 
              Property 'a' does not exist on type '{ b: number[]; }'.
    => error: Property 'b' does not exist on type '{ a: number; } | { b: number[]; }'.
              Property 'b' does not exist on type '{ a: number; }'
}
```

[example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Interface%20%7B%0D%0A%09AB%3F%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09a%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%20%7C%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09b%3A%20number%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20test(ab%3A%20Interface%5B'AB'%5D)%20%7B%0D%0A%09const%20ab2%20%3D%20('a'%20in%20ab!)%20%3F%20%5Bab!.a%5D%20%3A%20ab!.b%3B%0D%0A%7D)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `in` type-guard (and generally type-guards) will not work on expressions. So the expression `ab!` will not result in the narrowing of `ab`. For the type-guard to work, the guarded expression must be a simple parameter/variable/field. The simplest solution is to guard against `null` explicitly. This is probably a good idea since the field is optional anyway:

```
function test(ab: Interface['AB']) {
    const ab2 = !ab ? null : ('a' in ab) ? [ab.a] : ab.b;
}
```

Comment: It helped. Thank you :D